# Efficient Pagination In Postgresql (Keyset Pagination)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, pagination

I'm working on implementing pagination for a PostgreSQL database in which I have a table that stores users for my application. I have a query that is intended to fetch the next page of users based on their forename and creation timestamp. However, I'm encountering some difficulties and would appreciate some guidance.

Types for the columns:
userId (string  and stores uuidv5),
userForename (string),
userCreatedAt (timestamp)

Here's the query I'm using for fetching the next page:
 is just a placeholder

```
SELECT "userId", "userForename", "userCreatedAt"
FROM iatropolis."User"
WHERE
    LOWER("userForename") > 'aaliyah'
    OR (LOWER("userForename") = 'aaliyah' AND
     "userCreatedAt" > TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 14:50:39.481197')
ORDER BY "userForename" ASC, "userCreatedAt" ASC
LIMIT <limit>;
```

The goal of this query is to retrieve the first user after 'aaliyah' alphabetically, and if there are multiple users with the same forename, to select the one with a creation timestamp later than '2024-03-25 14:50:39.481197'.

However, I'm unsure if this query is correctly achieving the desired pagination. Even though I tested it and it outputted correct results, I don't know if it will behave in  the long run as desired (not sure if I am missing something).

I have also tried to go to the previous page buy creating a similar query.

```
SELECT "userId", "userForename", "userCreatedAt"
FROM iatropolis."User"
WHERE
    LOWER("userForename") < 'zula' 
    OR (LOWER("userForename") = 'zula' AND
     "userCreatedAt" < TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 14:51:53.062856')
ORDER BY "userForename" DESC, "userCreatedAt" DESC
LIMIT <limit>;
```

This is some ascending random data that I am working with:

| userId | userForename | userCreatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 38ee48f9-6d79-5690-9e51-df4b1cc5d428 | Aaliyah | 2024-03-25 14:50:39.481197 |
| ba2c1a86-280d-573f-ad35-ed1d023e3e5d | Aaliyah | 2024-03-25 14:51:35.52505 |
| 4f40dd7a-8f0f-54e4-bf14-3de3626bde67 | Abagail | 2024-03-25 19:27:10.985665 |
| e7b68316-188d-509e-9fd3-7fc780986c71 | Abbey | 2024-03-25 17:45:43.584704 |
| 1084f33e-9183-501d-b1af-70d61f1479d7 | Abbigail | 2024-03-25 19:27:29.720356 |
| 561e71fd-f04a-54d2-9864-2324e28cdfbd | Abbigail | 2024-03-25 19:27:35.5478 |
| ab5ad018-1866-50a4-8bf6-568f74988d21 | Abbigail | 2024-03-25 17:46:35.309003 |
| 596e13f2-e413-5b50-bdfb-9e68f0edf3db | Abdiel | 2024-03-25 17:47:08.576102 |
| d0d5bff9-f782-5451-bda4-e4d4a3e49f04 | Abdiel | 2024-03-25 14:51:24.257638 |
| 33a02ded-b354-5a6b-b506-cad3595d19be | Abdul | 2024-03-25 17:46:49.809666 |
| 6e1f68ff-f799-511e-ba91-83b35349e652 | Abdul | 2024-03-25 14:51:02.533247 |
| f67226da-a560-5913-9770-c23499046dc5 | Abe | 2024-03-25 14:49:34.342507 |
| 4e345a84-144d-55e2-a568-ce2064cb91fc | Abigale | 2024-03-25 19:26:32.349998 |
| ecab4167-8275-5c45-a6ce-5f616edeb60b | Abigale | 2024-03-25 19:26:24.406462 |
| 3689dc88-b57c-572b-90cd-3bd0c4603656 | Abigayle | 2024-03-25 14:50:41.608976 |
| db26cecb-0532-5cd4-b45e-04c14ce48b97 | Abigayle | 2024-03-25 19:26:54.081197 |
| 03d9e144-ba2e-5d08-b8bc-abaa42b59848 | Abner | 2024-03-25 17:47:12.313267 |
| e7d3fd8b-9187-5e78-8178-93eef85c3edc | Abner | 2024-03-25 19:27:35.016205 |
| 3a0c5db0-a19b-57b2-be99-6c0e0d33fb4c | adadadFN | 2024-03-22 11:33:03.466138 |
| daada509-45b3-58e8-920f-2441395af0f8 | Adalberto | 2024-03-25 17:46:31.150524 |
| dd3781a8-45ae-5ecb-9d5d-b4230347b0d8 | Adaline | 2024-03-25 17:46:05.821796 |
| c2122ddb-fd31-59ea-b5db-3e8696f0a2fc | Adan | 2024-03-25 14:51:06.880816 |
| 19ac3589-47ac-53ba-8e8c-c1537babbe97 | Addie | 2024-03-25 17:47:04.303399 |
| c61c8d3a-02b7-5db3-8b84-dba2fbf522b8 | Addie | 2024-03-25 17:46:35.627732 |
| 6800cc09-113a-5383-a9ec-463bfeb1f3aa | Addison | 2024-03-25 17:46:24.314788 |

This is some descending random data that I am working with:

| userId | userForename | userCreatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d64ce86e-1bf4-56d8-86dc-e0ffd9bae972 | Zula | 2024-03-25 14:51:53.062856 |
| e6f98b6c-ae16-58e9-ba3a-979dac63058d | Zora | 2024-03-25 17:46:15.697886 |
| 951b1493-0f86-5741-8b3d-5b7db7466f25 | Zora | 2024-03-25 14:51:38.315643 |
| a2c4455e-5333-57ea-9e7e-6a8ca03a7cf4 | Zita | 2024-03-25 19:26:44.119388 |
| d00c4951-de6a-5290-b956-13bf3b3e11eb | Zita | 2024-03-25 14:51:28.445206 |
| 390b6dae-b47e-57d7-8a7f-10a002d9b3a3 | Zion | 2024-03-25 14:50:18.578468 |
| 6f6371a0-b5bd-5839-aed2-81e8b8e0bff7 | Zetta | 2024-03-25 19:27:22.998847 |
| 4750df40-ffda-55e2-b26b-7c0c2ecf87e5 | Zetta | 2024-03-25 19:26:01.682206 |
| 14d137e7-83aa-5463-b47e-1a2376b53376 | Zelma | 2024-03-25 14:50:15.690687 |
| 0defcb46-486c-5273-9c81-e553500de614 | Zelma | 2024-03-25 14:49:32.577772 |
| 1a28a48b-bc3b-5f84-bbae-1ac0839bf311 | Zechariah | 2024-03-25 19:26:04.410123 |
| 574bf44e-2604-5ff1-95a9-164287d3c880 | Zane | 2024-03-25 19:27:15.455109 |
| e7b0e413-2eff-5240-8c18-321664a42416 | Zander | 2024-03-25 19:26:45.864325 |
| 2a737734-2c45-54c0-b911-315c8d333884 | Zakary | 2024-03-25 14:50:34.264419 |
| 782ddfaa-df67-50e3-841d-fa21b525e75c | Zackery | 2024-03-25 17:47:17.542445 |
| d24c75f2-7152-50aa-96ef-3a2d3847f1d3 | Zackary | 2024-03-25 17:46:58.029806 |
| c2d6d8c5-3891-57fb-bbea-57e22cb51da4 | Zack | 2024-03-25 17:46:27.203011 |
| 3333d2de-8028-5f00-8e4c-db821e8fe1a5 | Zachary | 2024-03-25 17:46:25.890929 |
| f11dfc68-78f1-5290-b203-9e04449c0538 | Zachary | 2024-03-25 14:50:27.447767 |
| d88c05bc-5fe4-5597-94b5-ca29c99a2df4 | Zachariah | 2024-03-25 17:46:52.98815 |
| cf8e2a99-e308-53ae-8908-8c2ff0188143 | Zachariah | 2024-03-25 14:51:47.465403 |
| da1ed730-9965-56c2-9317-e1726f172afc | Yvonne | 2024-03-25 19:26:36.714501 |
| 97a4213a-5fd5-5d0d-a860-567295ab9a23 | Yvonne | 2024-03-25 14:51:20.7755 |
| 41ce8c6b-5cca-57b9-a74b-d9fbf8f32ade | Yvette | 2024-03-25 14:50:18.973821 |
| 9f47693b-bcfd-5e2c-b92f-56aefb79ce03 | Yoshiko | 2024-03-25 19:27:33.647082 |

My question is somebody that knows SQL properly and used it for years and years, would agree that this keyset pagination is implemented properly? Also, for my case, being able to order the columns is very important, this being the reason of why I included the userForename in the queries. In the event that my queries are not correct, could somebody show me  how  to do them properly? Additionally, I am open to exploring alternative approaches if there are more efficient solutions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three key things you need to be able to use Keyset Pagination successfully.

- An `ORDER BY` on a **unique** set of columns.
- On subsequent pages, a `WHERE` clause on the same set of columns, specifying `>` in the **same** order.
- An index on those columns with the columns in the **same** order, either ascending or descending.

Your query doesn't appear to do that. Firstly, you aren't using a unique set of columns. You'd need to add `userId` probably, to ensure you get deterministic results.

Also, you need a supporting index on the same set of columns, so unless you have an index on `(LOWER(userForename), userCreatedAt, userId)` then it's not going to be performant. I'd advise to just set a case-insensitive collation, rather than using `LOWER`, and then an index `(userForename, userCreatedAt, userId)

```
SELECT
  userId,
  userForename,
  userCreatedAt
FROM iatropolis."User"
WHERE
    userForename > 'aaliyah'
    OR (userForename = 'aaliyah' AND
     userCreatedAt > TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 14:50:39.481197')
    OR (userForename = 'aaliyah' AND
     userCreatedAt = TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 14:50:39.481197' AND
     userId > '38ee48f9-6d79-5690-9e51-df4b1cc5d428')
ORDER BY
  userForename ASC,
  userCreatedAt ASC,
  userId ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that in Postgres and many other DBMSs you can just use a *row-comparator*.

```
SELECT
  userId,
  userForename,
  userCreatedAt
FROM iatropolis."User"
WHERE
    (userForename, userForename, userId) >
    ('aaliyah', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 14:50:39.481197', '38ee48f9-6d79-5690-9e51-df4b1cc5d428')
ORDER BY
  userForename ASC,
  userCreatedAt ASC,
  userId ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

For the previous page, just change `ASC` to `DESC` and `>` to `<`.

Side note: don't prefix every column with the table name, we know which table it's from. And don't quote column names unless necessary, it makes it hard to read.